# Differing "free memory" interpretation on virtualized vs. bare-metal Debian 9

Tags: linux, mysql, virtualization, memory, mongodb

I have the same software suite with roughly similarly sized datasets on two Debian 9 systems, with one big difference: `os-1` runs on bare-metal and has better hardware, while `os-2` is virtualized through VMWare, with somewhat less resources available.

During operation, while trying to break down overall memory usage into what each piece of software is using up, I've reached a point where I am not able to correlate the memory usage reports from the two OS'es anymore.  In particular:

### "top" and "free -m" on `os-1`

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
15451 mysql     20   0 9127356 998548 157856 S   0.0  2.4   3246:27 mysqld                                           
   42 root      20   0  271064 176612 176332 S   0.0  0.4  42:19.55 systemd-journal                                  
21979 mongodb   20   0 1616012 129260  35476 S   0.5  0.3 340:30.57 mongod                                           
  130 Debian-+  20   0  126644  78248   5820 S   0.0  0.2  83:17.46 snmpd                                            
  896 root      20   0  370140  36400  28452 S   0.0  0.1   3:06.93 apache2                                          
 1523 www-data  20   0  370212  11472   3480 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2

# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          40000        1131       32612        2398        6256       38868
Swap:          8191          85        8106
```

### "top" and "free -m" on `os-2`

```
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                         
 62285 mysql     20   0 2893200 690956      0 S   0.3  8.5  14097:36 mysqld                                          
 79420 mongodb   20   0 1815116 320700   2300 S   0.7  3.9 245:25.68 mongod                                          
104939 www-data  20   0  445412  39284  16596 S   0.7  0.5   0:21.56 apache2                                         
 97338 www-data  20   0  444964  38704  16480 S   0.3  0.5   0:41.19 apache2                                         
 97313 www-data  20   0  444836  38504  16416 S   0.7  0.5   0:40.33 apache2                                         
 97315 www-data  20   0  444636  38476  16608 S   0.7  0.5   0:42.21 apache2                                         
110249 www-data  20   0  444628  38236  16076 S   0.3  0.5   0:12.58 apache2      

# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7969        6067        1170          88         731        1571
Swap:          2927           0        2927
```

Based on my following observations:

- `os-1`'s reporting indicates that the overall usage is roughly the sum of its processes' RSS numbers (i.e. ~1.1GB), and NOT their VSZ'es, which would equate to over 11 GB of "used" memory.  Fair enough, let's move on!
- `os-2`'s reporting indicates that the overall usage is a much larger number than the sum of its processess' RSS values (6GB?!).  A number which I cannot explain anymore.

... what would be a next step in order to explain the root cause of the reported high memory usage on `os-2`?  Are there any critical memory-related virtualization concepts that I've omitted while drawing these conclusions?  Thank you!